# Define a set of values for a variable in shell script

Tags: shell-script, variable, array

I want to define a set of values for a single variable. E.g.

```
singleDigit={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

If the user gives 10 it should exit with an error.

How can this be achieved without using a loop, but an array instead?

Comment: Ok, but if i want to use string then?   i.e    name={"joy","tom"}     and you entered name as harry   . It should report error.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store several values into a variable, that's where you'd use an *array* like:

```
allowed_values=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Or

```
allowed_values=({0..9})
```

with `bash3+` (syntax borrowed from `zsh` now also available in `ksh93`).

And if you want to check whether a given string is among any of those values, you could define a function like:

```
isin() {
  local s
  for s in "${@:2}"; do
    [[ $1 = "$s" ]] && return 0
  done
  return 1
}

if isin "$input" "${allowed_values[@]}"
```

(in `zsh`, you can do `if ((allowed_values[(eI)$input]))`).

Note that the comparison is lexical (as in 01 != 1). Do do numerical comparison, you'd use `[ "$1" -eq "$s" ] 2> /dev/null` (note that `010` is `10`, not `8`). Do not use `[[ $1 -eq $s ]]` or `((s == $1))` as those introduce arbitrary command injection vulnerabilities.

---

If you want to assign a *pattern* to a variable to match against some input, you'd use a scalar variable and use one of the 2 (3 with the `extglob` option) pattern syntaxes supported by `bash`:

- wildcard/glob pattern

  ```
  pattern='[0-9]'
  ```

  Used as:

  ```
  case $input in
    ($pattern) echo OK;;
    (*) echo NOK
  esac
  ```

  or

  ```
  if [[ $input = $pattern ]]; then
    echo OK
  else
    echo NOK
  fi
  ```
- Extended Regular Expression:

  ```
  regex='^[0-9]$'
  ```

  used as:

  ```
  if [[ $input =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo OK
  else
    echo NOK
  fi
  ```

In the general case, for values other than single-character ones, you'd use:

```
regex='^(one|two|three)$'
```

And for *patterns*, you'd need the `extglob` option:

```
shopt -s extglob
pattern='@(one|two|three)'
```

---

Another approach with `bash4+`, or `ksh93` or `zsh` is to use an associative array:

With `bash`, `ksh93`:

```
typeset -A allowed_values
allowed_values=([one]=1 [two]=1 [three]=1)
if ((allowed_values[$input])); then
  echo OK
else
  echo NOK
fi
```

In `zsh`, same but the assignment syntax is:

```
typeset -A allowed_values
allowed_values=(one 1 two 1 three 1)
```

(note that with `bash`, you can't have the empty string as an allowed value).

Comment: What version of bash does `allowed_valaues=({0..9})` not work on?

Comment: @123, actually, it seems it's not as recent as I thought. `{x..y}` was added in bash 3 (2004),

Answer (score 0):

If only the numbers 0 through 9 are allowable as input, all you need is a simple IF statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n Please enter a single digit:
read single_digit
if [ $single_digit -lt 10 ]; then
   echo Thanks for $single_digit
else
   echo Screwball!!! I said SINGLE DIGIT!!
fi
```