# Comparing multiple options in a bash (string)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I'm trying to enable only certain options when using the `read` command, and to exit the script if a wrong possibility was entered.

Tried many possibilities (array, variables, syntax change), but I'm still stuck with my initial problem.

How do I test the input of the user and allow \ disallow to run the rest of the script?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

red=$(tput setaf 1)
textreset=$(tput sgr0) 

echo -n 'Please enter requested region > '
echo 'us-east-1, us-west-2, us-west-1, eu-central-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-northeast-1, ap-southeast-2, ap-northeast-2, ap-south-1, sa-east-1'
read text

if [ -n $text ] && [ "$text" != 'us-east-1' -o us-west-2 -o us-west-1 -o eu-central-1 -o ap-southeast-1 -o ap-northeast-1 -o ap-southeast-2 -o  ap-northeast-2 -o ap-south-1 -o sa-east-1 ] ; then 

echo 'Please enter the region name in its correct form, as describe above'

else

echo "you have chosen ${red} $text ${textreset} region."
AWS_REGION=$text

echo $AWS_REGION

fi
```

Comment: See also [Define a set of values for a variable in shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297077)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you use case?

```
case $text in 
  us-east-1|us-west-2|us-west-1|eu-central-1|ap-southeast-1|etc) 
         echo "Working"
  ;;

  *)
         echo "Invalid option: $text"
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Great answer! simple and easy, I've even added an error message in case anyone just press 'enter' (which display $text as an empty field- so although it is the correct behavior, it seems like an error)(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575392/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-string-in-a-bash-case-statement)

Comment: You can add this clause "") echo "Please enter some data" ;;. Note that it needs to come first than *) clause.

Answer (score 8):

Why not make the life of the user a bit easier by not requiring them to type the name of the region at all?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Select region"

PS3="region (1-10): "

select region in "us-east-1" "us-west-2" "us-west-1" "eu-central-1" \
    "ap-southeast-1" "ap-northeast-1" "ap-southeast-2" \
    "ap-northeast-2" "ap-south-1" "sa-east-1"
do
    if [[ -z $region ]]; then
        printf 'Invalid choice: "%s"\n' "$REPLY" >&2
    else
        break
    fi
done

printf 'You have chosen the "%s" region\n' "$region"
```

If the user types in anything other than a valid numerical option from the list, the value in `$region` will be an empty string, and we display an error message.  If the choice is valid, the loop exits.

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh
Select region
1) us-east-1         4) eu-central-1     7) ap-southeast-2  10) sa-east-1
2) us-west-2         5) ap-southeast-1   8) ap-northeast-2
3) us-west-1         6) ap-northeast-1   9) ap-south-1
region (1-10): aoeu
Invalid choice: "aoeu"
region (1-10): .
Invalid choice: "."
region (1-10): -1
Invalid choice: "-1"
region (1-10): 0
Invalid choice: "0"
region (1-10): '
Invalid choice: "'"
region (1-10): 5
You have chosen the "ap-southeast-1" region
```

Comment: Very nice answer, and it introduced to me `select var in ...; do ... ; done`, which I had never saw nor used in many decades of bash usage...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with this:

```
[ "$text" != 'us-east-1' -o us-west-2 -o ... ]
```

The `-o` means *or* and you need a full condition, so it would be

```
[ "$text" != 'us-east-1' -o "$text" != 'us-west-2' -o ... ]
```

See how we're having to test `$text` each time?

Your *logic* is also wrong; you want `-a` (*and*); if it's not "us-east-1" *and* it's not "us-west-2" *and* it's not...

So

```
[ "$text" != 'us-east-1' -a "$text" != 'us-west-2' -a ... ]
```

There are other ways of doing this sort of test; some of which are merely "personal preference".  However this syntax should get you going and follows the form and structure of your original.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, It seems I did messed up the logic- oddly enough I did try it like you said, I guess I was too tired..

Answer (score 2):

I really can't stand scripts that ask me questions rather than allow me to use command line options (easier to edit and re-use previous command lines, easier to use in a script), so I'd use `getopts` like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

regions=(us-east-1 us-west-2 us-west-1 eu-central-1 ap-southeast-1
         ap-northeast-1 ap-southeast-2 ap-northeast-2 ap-south-1
         sa-east-1)

region=0  # default to region 0, us-east-1

usage() {
  [ -n "$1" ] && printf '%s\n\n' "$@"

  echo "Usage: $0 [ -r region-number|\"list\"] ..."
  # print more help here
  exit 1
}

list_regions() {
  [ -n "$1" ] && printf '%s\n\n' "$@"

  printf '%s\n' "${regions[@]}" | cat -n
  exit 1
}

check_region() {
  [ "$region" == "list" ] && list_regions
  [[ ! "$region" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && usage "Region code must be numeric"

  region=$((region - 1))  # bash arrays are zero-based
  [ -z "${regions[$region]}" ] || \
    [ "$region" -lt 0 ] && list_regions "Unknown region code"
}

while getopts 'r:h' opt ; do
  case "$opt" in
     r) region="$OPTARG" ; check_region ;;

     h) usage ;;
     *) usage ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# do whatever with "$region" and/or "${regions[$region]}"
echo region="${regions[$region]}"
```

Some example runs:

```
$ ./busted.sh 
region=us-east-1
$ ./busted.sh -r
./busted.sh: option requires an argument -- r
Usage: ./busted.sh [-r region-number|"list"] ...
$ ./busted.sh -r list
     1  us-east-1
     2  us-west-2
     3  us-west-1
     4  eu-central-1
     5  ap-southeast-1
     6  ap-northeast-1
     7  ap-southeast-2
     8  ap-northeast-2
     9  ap-south-1
    10  sa-east-1
$ ./busted.sh -r 99
Unknown region code

     1  us-east-1
     2  us-west-2
     3  us-west-1
     4  eu-central-1
     5  ap-southeast-1
     6  ap-northeast-1
     7  ap-southeast-2
     8  ap-northeast-2
     9  ap-south-1
    10  sa-east-1
$ ./busted.sh -r 7
region=ap-southeast-2
```

Comment: Hellow friend, very nice script! +1

Comment: thanks.  on looking at this again, it's a little too verbose for my liking so I'd probably make the "Unknown region code" error message just say `use '-r list' for a list` rather than printing the entire list.  and use `column` or something in the `list_regions` function so that the list didn't take up so many output lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
valid=(foo bar doo)
echo enter something, valid values: "${valid[@]}"
read text
ok=0
for x in "${valid[@]}" ; do 
    if [ "$text" = "$x" ] ; then ok=1 ; fi ; 
done 
echo is it ok: $ok
```

The valid values are saved in a bash array, which can be used both for display and to test the input string.

Apart from the fact that `-o` in `test` need a full condition, there are also arguments that one shouldn't use

```
[ "$x" != "foo" -a "$x" != "bar" ]
```

but instead

```
[ "$x" != "foo" ] && [ "$x" != "bar" ]
```